# What props is for in this example

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Why are "props" put in this code? I tried deleting both props and the result was the same. So, what props are for?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Car extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      brand: "Ford",
      model: "Mustang",
      color: "red",
      year: 1964
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>My {this.state.brand}</h1>
        <p>
          It is a {this.state.color}
          {this.state.model}
          from {this.state.year}.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Car />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Props in general are used to pass data from parent to child component. In this example, you don't use the props at all. That's why you get the same result
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: Can you check this screenshot to see if I understood it right? https://ibb.co/9ZCrdFD

Comment: Yeah, that looks ok to me. Does it work correctly?

Comment: Yes, it print's mustang... I'm learning React now and this was example from w3s that I didn't understood but if comments on this screenshot are correct then I understand it now :D

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to guess what the author had in mind, if you can't contact them directly.  But since passing along properties doesn't add overhead that wasn't already there, it's *probably* for either future expansion or to get the reader accustomed to seeing the `props` used, depending on where the example comes from.

They're not used in this component, as you point out, but most React developers I've worked with prefer to automatically include an empty `props` in each component when writing them, rather than remembering to go back to add the parameter and call to `super()` when specifically needed.

That is, for a lot of programmers, it's simpler to just make `props` part of every component than to risk adding a property later and being stressed when the error message shows up complaining that `this.props.property` is trying to access `null`.

Comment: can you check if I understood it right? https://ibb.co/9ZCrdFD

Comment: @NemanjaTrajkovic, that looks right to me. Just to confirm that you're not having a problem that I can't spot on a screenshot, does the page display correctly? When you modify the `brand` object, does that change the display?

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand it?
https://ibb.co/9ZCrdFD
This is screenshot of comments in code